# Remove file path from "FilePathResult" keep only FileName.Extention

Tags: c#, filepath

I have following code snippet

```
var fileResult = path as FilePathResult;
```

for above code snippet I'm getting long file path ,

Something like `D:\Projects\Upload_Images\A.jpeg`

I want to remove this `D:\Projects\Upload_Images\` from above path and keep only `A.jpeg`

how can I do this easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) will do the trick for you as it returns the file name and extension of the specified path string.

```
string fileName = @"D:\Projects\Upload_Images\A.jpeg";
string result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```